# dealloc old SKscene Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

Im trying to do a transition between two SKScenes. But currently when I run my code and present the new SKScene (Through a button pressed) the new scene is presented and runs perfectly except that some elements contained in the passed scene still are present (a button and the background)
According to Apple's Sprite Kit Programming Guide (For Obj.-c) page 66 "The strong reference to the old scene is automatically removed" and if that is the case I don't understand why I still have elements from my old scene. And how do I dealloc the old scene so nothing is present in my new scene and also for memory purposes. Here is the code on how Im presenting my new scene this code is inside my Menu.swift not in my GameViewController.swift scene:

```
func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!) {       

    let skView = self.view? as SKView?
    skView?.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    let gamingScene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 1024, height: 768))
    gamingScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView?.presentScene(gamingScene)   

}
```

Comment: UI elements, such as UiButtons and UiViews, must be manually removed from the SKView when you transition to a new scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because UI elements are added as a "subview" these does not depend of the SKScene. So you have to remove them before presenting the new scene.

Use this line code to remove UIElements

```
self.buttonAcion.removeFromSuperview()
```